# How to send multiline data in curl body within bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, curl, json

I am trying to send multi-line comment in the `curl` body from `bash` script. Below is my `curl` invocation.

```
#!/bin/bash

temp="This is sample data: 2019/05/21 03:33:04
      This is 2nd sample data: #2 Sample_Data"

response=$(curl -sS --location "${HEADERS[@]}" -w "%{http_code}\n" -X POST "$url" --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
                        --data-raw  "{
                                \"id\" : \"111\",
                                \"status\" : {
                                .
                                .
                                .
                                \"details\" : [ \"$temp\" ]
                                }
                        }")
echo "$response"
```

In the actual script the variable `temp` is `stdout`. So, it will be a multi-line output.
If I try above script I get below error:

```
{"exceptionClass":"xxx.exception.MessageNotReadableException","errorCode":"xxx.body.notReadable","message":"The given request body is not well formed"}400
```

Can anyone please let me know what is the issue and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Since this seems to be JSON, there's no technical need for the line breaks in the data. A JSON parser doesn't care.

Comment: Anyway, the web server is quite specific in that your request **body** is not well formed. So we can't help you here - you are omitting a significant part of the request, so that nobody can verify the well-formedness of your JSON.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks for the update. But what is the general way of sending multi-line data in body? Do you have any examples for this? In my case the issue is only with variable `\"details\" : [ \"$temp\" ]` . If `temp` is single line then it's working fine..

Comment: You're currently sending multiline data. Your problem has nothing to do with that. Again, JSON doesn't care about line breaks, either.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Those newline characters in the `$temp` string needs to be JSON encoded, so the multiline data _is_ the issue. I'm pretty sure there is a duplicate question somewhere.

Comment: @Kusalananda yes this could help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JSON string can't contain literal newlines. You can't take a shell variable and inject it into a JSON document without first properly JSON-encoding the variable's value.

One way to encode the string is by using `jq`:

```bash
status_details=$( jq -n --arg string "$temp" '$string' )
```

Note that `$string` in the command above is an internal `jq` variable, not a shell variable. The `jq` utility would encode the value given to `$string` on the command line and output it as a JSON-encoded string.

Given your example code, this would set the `status_details` variable to the following literal string, including the quotes:

```json
"This is sample data: 2019/05/21 03:33:04\n      This is 2nd sample data: #2 Sample_Data"
```

You may then use this in your call to `curl`:

```bash
curl -s -S -L -w '%{http_code}\n' -X POST \
    --data-raw '{ "id": "111", "status": { "details": [ '"$status_details"' ] } }' \
    "$url"
```

If the `details` array is for storing each line from `$temp` as individual elements, you may split `$temp` into an array with `jq` like so:

```bash
status_details=$( jq -n --arg string "$temp" '$string | split("\n")' )
```

This would give you the following literal sting in `$status_details`:

```json
[
  "This is sample data: 2019/05/21 03:33:04",
  "      This is 2nd sample data: #2 Sample_Data"
]
```

You could then use that with `curl` in pretty much the same way as shown above, but without surrounding `$status_details` with square brackets (`... "details": '"$status_details"' ...`).

Comment: Hello @Kusalananda thanks for your answer. Your solution looks promising. But I still get `"The given request body is not well formed"}400` error. I think this is becasue of quotes `""` in `$status_details`. Is it possible to trim them? Tried `jq -r` option `$( jq -r -n --arg string "$temp" '$string' )`

Comment: Update: Adding `| tr -d '"'` worked.

Comment: @Preeti You _definitely_ should not need to trim the double quotes away! I'm assuming you are trying to insert `$status_details` in place of `$temp` in _your_ code while ignoring the code that I used in my answer which was tailored to the way `$status_details` was created.